# Differential equation $x^2y''-xy'+2y=x\ln{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Hello there I am trying to solve $$x^2y''-xy'+2y=xe^x$$ I thought to use  Laplace transform after rewriting as $$(-x)^2y''+(-x)y'+2y=-(-x)e^x$$thus $$F''(s)+F'(s)+2F(s)=-\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right)'$$ but now I dont know how to solve: $$F''(s)+F'(s)+2F(s)=\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}$$ Taking $z''+z'+2z=0\,$ For the homogeneous equation I have found $$r^2+r+2=0$$ giving $$r_{1,2}=\frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{7}}{2}$$ thus $$z_0=e^{-\frac{1}{2}p}\left(c_1\cos{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}p}+c_2\sin{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}p}\right)$$ I would appreciate some help with this. Edit: It was supposed to be: $$x^2y''-xy'+2y=x\ln{x}$$ But I have no ideea how to do the Laplace of the RHS now.

Comment: the general solution to the homogeneous differential equation can be found easily, and you can use "Variation of Parameters" to find the particular solution

Comment: the answer is cumbersome

Comment: The solution is not really simple..

Comment: lol it's far from being simple lol ....I tried  Euler's method and got for the inhomogenous part $e^ze^{e^z}$ not that easy

Comment: It's easy with Euler' substitution it's feasable

Comment: The Laplace transform of $x\ln(x)$ is $$\frac{1-\gamma-\ln(s)}{s^2}$$

Comment: What equation is the given task, the one in the title or the one in the first formula of the text?

Comment: @LutzL I think it's the one in the edit

Comment: Well. The one in the title because the other one had not elementary solution according to wolfram, however I had as a homework (not recently so I cant ask my teacher) the one in the first formula.

Comment: @Frpzzd Yes I saw that on wolfram, any hints on how to get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm solving the equation in your edit and not in the initial text.

Laplace transform is not needed here (you don't have initial conditions). The equation is much easier than it looks. If you didn't know, this is a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation), which can be solved using the substitution $x = e^t$:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - 2\frac{dy}{dt} + 2y = te^t $$

The homogeneous solution is solved by the characteristic equation

$$ r^2 - 2r + 2 = 0 \implies r = 1 \pm i $$
$$ \implies y_h = c_1e^t\cos t + c_2e^t\sin t $$

The particular solution can be solved using undetermined coefficients

$$ y_p = (At+B)e^t \implies y_p = te^t $$

Putting it together

\begin{align} 
y &= te^t + c_1e^t\cos t + c_2e^t\sin t \\ 
&= x\ln x + c_1x\cos(\ln x) + c_2x\sin(\ln x) 
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

I assume that if you want to use Laplace Transform is because you have the initial conditions $\ y(0)=0\ $ and $\ y'(0)=0\ $

If I was you, I'd avoid LT cause is not so easy like in constants terms ODEs.

The easiest way is visualizing that the ODE has a No Homogeneous Cauchy Euler Form

Let $\ y=x^m\ $ then do the derivatives and substitute in the Homogeneous Part of the ODE

$$y_h(x)=x[C_1\cos(\ln|x|))+C_2\sin(\ln|x|)]$$

Apply Variation of Parameters where $y_1=x\cos(\ln|x|)\ $,$\ y_2=x\sin(\ln|x|)$ and the $f(x)$ for the Wronskians $\ W=x\ $, $\ W_1=-\ln|x|\sin(\ln|x|)\ $, $\ W_2=\ln|x|\cos(\ln|x|)\ $ is

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln|x|}{x}$$

Then $$u_1=\int\frac{W_1}{W}\qquad u_2=\int\frac{W_2}{W}$$
$$y_p(x)=y_1u_1+y_2u_2\\ y_p(x)=-x\ln|x|$$

$$y(x)=x\left\{C_1\cos(\ln|x|))+C_2\sin(\ln|x|)-\ln|x|\right\}$$

I hope anyone can solve it by LT like you want it.

If is a IVP centered in 0, is undefined for the $\ln|x|$ and you can't evaluate it unless you make an numerical aproximation, thus LT doesn't work.

Comment: I think the $y(0)=0$ is a good initial condition, because $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} y(x)=0$, but it won't tell anything about the constants.

Comment: The first condition its right cause 0=0, but the second the limit of $\ \cos(\ln(x))\ $, and $\ \sin(\ln(x))\ $ in 0 its undefined.

Comment: You are right! Not even the $C_1=C_2=0$ will solve that.

Comment: you can apply laplace operator but it really can't do more than that, you must know the condition around 0 in order to get the right transformation in the Frecuency Domain. Your Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that with the substitution $x=e^t$, $u(t)=y(e^t)$ on the equatio in the title, the equation becomes a linear DE with constant coefficients
$$
\ddot u-2\dot u+2u=te^t.
$$
That should be easy to solve with what ever method, Laplace transform, undetermined coefficients etc.